# Overlay Google Maps Normal tiles in the Google Earth Api

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to overlay the Normal Google Map Tiles(type: G_NORMAL_MAP) inside of the Google Earth Web Api.  The satellite maps have too inconsistent of contrast for the layers I want to display.

Any help would be appreciated on if this is possible, and if it is a direction on how to do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, unfortunately:

1. There is no 'roadmap' or 'normal' map type in the Google Earth API. So that rules out the easy route.
2. The tiles used in Google Earth are unprojected, while Google Maps tiles are served in a roughly-Mercator projection. Although theoretically you could unproject Google Maps tiles so that they would align properly with Google Earth tiles, *this is strictly prohibited* by the [Google Maps Terms of Service](http://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html) and/or the [Google Maps/Earth API Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html).

Though I admit, it would be pretty cool :-)

Comment: Yeah I'm just trying to figure out how to get rid of the massive contrast variations that come from the satellite maps.  Looks like I'm going to have to use my own tiles.  Thanks!